# What does '#' operator in front of a variable do in variable expansion?

Tags: shell

below is the code I executed in terminal

```
[root@idm ~]# x="$(date +%d%m%y)"    
[root@idm ~]# echo $x
270217
[root@idm ~]# echo ${#x}
6
```

Can someone help me understand why the output is `6`? What is `#` essentially doing to the variable?

Comment: I know this is old but please don't run these as root. There's no need to be root for this. I know it's easy to get into the habit but ***unless you absolutely NEED* root** do **NOT** use it! That cannot be overstated! .. which I see at least one answer says .. but still worth pointing out here.

Answer (score 32):

It's a parameter expansion that returns the length of the parameter, or the number of elements in an array, or the number of positional parameters.

Please read your shell's manual. The following is from the `bash` manual:

> `${#parameter}`
>
> **The length in characters of the value of `parameter` is substituted**. If `parameter` is `*` or `@`, the value
>                 substituted is the number of positional parameters.  If
>                 `parameter` is an array name subscripted by `*` or `@`, the value
>                 substituted is the number of elements in the array.  If
>                 `parameter` is an indexed array name subscripted by a negative
>                 number, that number is interpreted as relative to one greater
>                 than the maximum index of parameter, so negative indices count
>                 back from the end of the array, and an index of -1 references
>                 the last element.

---

And also, *please* don't make a habit of working in an interactive root shell.  It's dangerous and reckless at best.  Use `sudo` sparingly and only in situations that requires elevated privileges. Playing around with `bash` is something you definitely can do as an ordinary non-root user.

In the last few years, I've only used an interactive root shell for manually adding a single user for myself. It's a 2-minute job and then I *never* need to see a `#` prompt ever again on that machine.

Comment: I use debian and  `apt` works with `root`, not without. So I need it to install a package. If i change `sshd_config` I also need root.

Comment: @Timo Yes? I'm assuming you're commenting on the last part of my answer? Of course you need to be root for certain operations, that's common.  What I'm saying is that logging in as root and working with an interactive root shell is _extremely_ dangerous and unnecessary.  Just [search for the word "accidentally"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=accidentally) on this site.  You edit `sshd_config` as root from a non-root account using `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_conf`, not by first bringing up an interactive shell.

Comment: @Timo the point is: there's no need to be root for running the `date` (and many other) commands.

Comment: As for this answer the fact it brings up root (which I just noted in a comment in the OP) is worth a point by itself. It cannot be overstated.

Answer (score 15):

The `#` operator returns the length of a variable. In your case the variable `x` length is six.

Please do have a look at [Parameter Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for more information.